# NGINX proxy to GCS bucket with redirect all urls to index.html, getting 200 blank responses on nested routes

Tags: nginx, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am configuring a reverse-proxy from NGINX to a GCP Cloud Storage bucket containing static HTML, JS, image files, with a rewrite for all non-matching URLS to index.html since it is a single-page-application.

Config:

```
user nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include           /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type      application/octet-stream;
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for" upstream: "$upstream_addr"';
    access_log        /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    server_tokens     off;

    sendfile        on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    gzip              on;
    gzip_disable      "msie6";
    gzip_comp_level   6;
    gzip_min_length   1100;
    gzip_buffers      16 8k;
    gzip_proxied      any;
    gzip_types
        text/plain
        text/css
        text/js
        text/xml
        text/javascript
        application/javascript
        application/x-javascript
        application/json
        application/xml
        application/xml+rss;

    resolver          8.8.8.8 valid=300s ipv6=off;
    resolver_timeout  10s;

    upstream gcs {
       server          storage.googleapis.com:443;
       keepalive       128;
    }


    proxy_cache_path      /var/cache/nginx keys_zone=google-cloud-storage:10m inactive=1h;
    proxy_cache           google-cloud-storage;
    proxy_cache_key       "$host/$proxy_host$uri";
    proxy_cache_valid     200 1m;


    server {
        listen          8080;

        recursive_error_pages on;

        if ( $request_method !~ "GET|HEAD" ) {
            return 405;
        }

        location = / {
            rewrite ^.*$ /index.html last;
        }

        location = /healthz/ {
            access_log off;
            return 200;
        }

        location / {
            proxy_set_header        Host storage.googleapis.com;
            proxy_set_header        Cookie "";
            proxy_set_header        Authorization "";
            proxy_set_header        Connection "";
            proxy_hide_header       x-goog-hash;
            proxy_hide_header       x-goog-generation;
            proxy_hide_header       x-goog-metageneration;
            proxy_hide_header       x-goog-stored-content-encoding;
            proxy_hide_header       x-goog-stored-content-length;
            proxy_hide_header       x-goog-storage-class;
            proxy_hide_header       x-guploader-uploadid;
            proxy_hide_header       x-xss-protection;
            proxy_hide_header       x-goog-meta-goog-reserved-file-mtime;
            proxy_hide_header       accept-ranges;
            proxy_hide_header       alternate-protocol;
            proxy_hide_header       Set-Cookie;
            proxy_hide_header       Expires;
            proxy_hide_header       Cache-Control;
            proxy_ignore_headers    Set-Cookie;
            proxy_http_version      1.1;
            proxy_intercept_errors  on;
            proxy_method            GET;
            proxy_pass_request_body off;

            proxy_ignore_headers    "Expires" "Cache-Control";


            add_header              X-Cache $upstream_cache_status;



            error_page              404 =200 /index.html;



            expires 1h;
            add_header Cache-Control "private";


            proxy_pass              https://gcs/my-bucket-name$uri;
        }
    }
}
```

So here's the issue:

1. **Without** a `proxy_cache` present, first request to **/nested/path** returns 200 OK with index.html
2. A soft reload from the browser sends headers `if-modified-since` and/or `if-none-match` headers to the proxy, but gets a **200 OK response with blank content**. (It should really be 304?)
3. A hard reload returns 200 with the correct index.html content.
4. **With** a `proxy_cache` present, 304 is correctly returned.
5. Request to **root path** / behaves correctly without a `proxy_cache`.

How can I ensure correct behavior on a soft reload without a `proxy_cache`?

Answer (score 2):

I could not make this work in any way, although here is a supposedly working example: https://github.com/presslabs/gs-proxy

I ended up mounting the bucket and simply using nginx by the file system.

See https://github.com/maciekrb/gcs-fuse-sample

Comment: I got that gs-proxy example working by deploying the container into Cloud Run. I had to fix the listen port to be 8080, then I had to make the content of the bucket be publicly accessible. It seems like there's no easy way to have the nginx service pass through the authentication credentials to the cloud storage API so you can't use this approach if you want any of your website to be non-public with access controlled by nginx.

Answer (score 1):

You could try with something like this:

```
    location = / {
        proxy_pass http://www.mybucket.com/index.html;
    }

    location ~* /(.*)$ {
        rewrite /(.*) / ;
    }
```

A CNAME record should exist for www.mybucket.com pointing to storage.googleapis.com and the single page application router should manage the 404 cases.